# Cutting already installed tile?

Tags: flooring, tile, floor, laminate-floor

I am planning on installing floating laminate flooring in my hallway among other places in my house. I wanted to take out the tile on the outside of this small bathroom and I wanted to wait to replace the tile flooring in my bathroom until I could replace the toilet, vanity and molding inside the bathroom at the same time. I am not sure how thick this tile is but it seems to be fairly sturdy. I was wondering, is it possible for me to make a cut in this tile at the door jamb where the laminate transition will go and cleanly take out all the tile outside of the bathroom while leaving all the tile inside the bathroom without chipping it? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to need two tools to do this and two specialty blades. A diamond cut-off disc to make the majority of the cut attached to a grinder. And you'll need a diamond (if available) or carbide-tipped oscillator bit and the corresponding oscillating tool ( sometimes called a multi-tool). For the majority of the cut you will use that diamond cut off disc with a wet sponge, a very wet sponge touching the blade obviously being very careful. Due to the diameter of the diamond disc you can't get right into the corners that's where the oscillating tool comes in handy. The oscillator will allow you to complete the cut right to the edge and then you can remove the tiles as required.

If you don't own these tools they should be available for rent but as a do-it-yourselfer both an oscillator and a grinder are essential.

Comment: So would something like this work? A PORTER CABLE PCE606K - 3-Amp 11-Piece Oscillating Multi Tool Kit along with a UNIVERSAL FIT 2-1/2" DIAMOND-GRIT OSCILLATING SAW BLADE.

Comment: Exactly, only thing is I'm not aware of any oscillating bit specific to cutting tile. I've done it with dimond embedded and carbide. I find the dimond works best. It's still a bit tough and doing it wet seems to help.

Comment: You can also use a dremel tool with a diamond wheel for that last inch or two. I would also cut right along the grout line for the left side of the doorway.

Comment: I will never buy another porter cable tool. I bought a brand new Porter cable oscillating tool and it failed in one year.  I understand that occasionally the lemon gets through but I attempted to contact customer service at Porter cable **twice**   And they refused to respond to me so they’ve lost a customer.

Comment: I've never used porter cable, I'm on team red/black and teal/black. Milwaukee and Makita have always been good to me.